# Vuetify trigger a tooltip

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify, and I have a tooltip over a button.
I doesn't want to show the tooltip on hover nor on click, I want to show the tooltip if some event is triggered.

**translate.vue**

```
<v-tooltip v-model="item.showTooltip" top>
  <template v-slot:activator="{}">
    <v-btn @click="translateItem(item)"> Call API to translate</v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>API quota limit has been reached</span>
</v-tooltip>


<script>
export default(){
  props: {
    item: { default: Objet}
  }
 methods: {
   translateItem: function (item) {
     axios
       .post(baseURL + "/translateAPI", {
         text: item.originTrad;
       })
       .then((res) => {
          if (apiQuotaLimitReached(res) { 
            // If limit is reached I want to show the tooltip for some time
            item.showTooltip = true;
            setTimeout(() => {item.showTooltip = false;}, 3000);
            } else  { ..... }}}
</script>
```

**itemSelect.vue** (where I create object item and then use router push to transmit it to the translation page)

```
<script>
export default(){
 methods: {
   createItem: function () {
     item.originTrad = "the text to translate"
     ....
     item.showTooltip = false;
     this.$router.push({
       name: "translate",
       params: {
            "item": item,
       },
     });  }}
</script>
```

As you can see I removed the `v-slot:activator="{ on }"` and `v-on="on"` that I found on the exemple:https://vuetifyjs.com/fr-FR/components/tooltips/ , because I don't want to show the tooltip on hover. But It doesn't work as expected, the tooltip is not showing properly.
Some help would be great :)

Comment: Have you tried using Vue.set(item, 'showTooltip', true) instead of direct assignment to property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you are trying to change a prop in the child component, something that you should not do:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
> overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
> data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
> mutated: "item.showTooltip"

So start by making a separate data variable for showTooltip (doesn't need to be a property of item perse) and try setting it to true to see what happens (and of course change `v-model="item.showTooltip"` to `v-model="showTooltip"` on v-tooltip)

Comment: Thank you, that works, but It doesn't solve everything, I didn't told you to simplify my problem but I have a v-for on this v-tooltip so I have several button 'translate' each corresponding to an item to translate. So It works but it show the tooltip on every buttons, (I would like to show the tooltip on the only one that was clicked)

Comment: Maybe I need to create a custom component and after I need to do a v-for on this component, like that I should have one 'showTooltip' for every item and it will probably resolve my problem